# In R, find full or partial matches of a string in one column with a second column

Tags: r

I need to compare an 8 to 10-character string in a column with another 8 to 10-character string in a second column, and add an asterisk to the first string if at least the first 8 digits match. I can manage an exact match, but I don't know how to manage the partial matches.

Can someone please help? I have the below code:

```
tl<-c("10012908","1001290810","10111090")
trqs<-as.data.frame(tl)

tl<-c("10012908","10012910")
mfn<-as.data.frame(tl)

for(i in 1:nrow(trqs)){
if(trqs$tl[i] %in% mfn$tl){
  trqs$tl[i] <-paste0(trqs$tl[i],"*")
  }
}

#the result should be:
trqs$tl<-c("10012908*","1001290810*","10111090")
```

Comment: I see single column examples but have you tried grep?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do it if the string that I am looking for changes each time based on the row -- is it possible with grep/ grepl?

Comment: I do not understand the question, if the solution I posted bellow is not helpful, let me know to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tl<-c("10012908","1001290810","10111090")
trqs<-as.data.frame(tl)
trqs$tl1<-c("10012908","1001290810","1090")
trqs[grep(paste(trqs$tl,collapse="|"),trqs$tl1),"tl1"]<-paste0(trqs[grep(paste(trqs$tl,collapse="|"),trqs$tl1),"tl1"],"*")
trqs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `substr` to match the first 8 characters.

First, create a vector `mfn_match` that will contain the first 8 characters from your `mfn` data.frame column of interest. Then you only need to do this once.

Next, create a logical vector `trqs_match` for those where the first 8 characters of `tl` in `trqs` match at least one element of `mfn_match`. For those matches, add an asterisk.

```
mfn_match <- substr(mfn$tl, 1, 8)
trqs_match <- sapply(trqs$tl, function(x) substr(x, 1, 8) %in% mfn_match)
trqs$tl[trqs_match] <- paste0(trqs$tl[trqs_match], "*")
trqs
```

**Output**

```
           tl
1   10012908*
2 1001290810*
3    10111090
```